# R: Having one function call other functions as well as passing arguments on to them

Tags: r, function, arguments, environment-variables

I have a series of functions like this one:

```
otherfunction<-function(x, y){
     if(option=="one"){
         z<-x+y+var
     }
     if(option=="two"){
         z<-x-y+2*var
     }
     return(z)
 }
```

Then a master function that defines arguments that need to be passed, along with output of the internal function,  on to other internal functions functions, as well as .

```
master <- function(x, y, option=c("one", "two"), variable=0.1){
    w <- otherfunction(x,y)
    #(or otherfunction(x,y, option, variable))     
    v <- otherfunction(w,y)
    return(v)
}
```

I seem to be getting stuck with either "object not found" or "unused arguments" errors.

How do other people deal with having multiple functions that will be called from a master function? 
Do I need to turn the values of the arguments in the master function into objects?

Does this need to be done in the global environment?

Do I need to define the "otherfunction"s within the master function?

Do I need to use some kind of "..." argument?

Or is there something else I'm not getting?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `otherfunction` has no way to see the `option` value from your `master` function. Functions look for variables in the environment where they are defined, not where they are called. This should work

```
otherfunction<-function(x, y, option, var){
    if(option=="one"){
        z<-x+y+var
    }
    if(option=="two"){
        z<-x-y+2*var
    }
    return(z)
}

master <- function(x, y, option=c("one", "two"), variable=0.1){
    w <- otherfunction(x,y, option, variable)
    v <- otherfunction(w,y, option, variable)
    return(v)
}
master(2,2, "two")
# [1] -1.6
```

If you wanted to pass through parameter, you could also do something like this with `master`

```
master <- function(x, y, ...){
    w <- otherfunction(x,y, ...)
    v <- otherfunction(w,y, ...)
    return(v)
}
master(2,2, option="two", var=0.1)
# [1] -1.6
```